# Facebook share with one-page application

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

This question may be not related to exact software stack, framework or language.

For my current project, we are using AngularJS to build the front-end that has a constant entrance page to load real data and render, which is easy for CDN and good for fast loading speed from browser side. But for some social feature, such architect may result in some problem. For example, when you paste your interested link to Facebook portal to share, Facebook will grab your page and show up a preview. If a landing page is empty, such preview won't work.

(I heard that Google+ recently support rendering javascript logic at server side before send back a preview, but obviously it's not a common support for other similar services. Google.com also supports indexing js based one-page application.)

Is there a better solution to solve this problem gracefully rather than fallback to have dynamic page which includes real data? Have I missed something in understanding this problem?

========

... I was even thinking of that, for requests that identified as FB request (like user agent), redirect it to a special gateway that wrapping sth like PhantomJS, fetch the page, render it server-side, and send back a DOM tree snapshot as content for FB to generate preview. But I also doubt that it's a good direction. : (

Comment: If you're using node I created a module that can help you render in the server the right page for fb or google to read. https://www.npmjs.org/package/googlebot

Comment: Hi @dvidsilva, it would be nice for google bot to work as a reverse proxy for the actual web application. If the front-end web server identified the bot request (like by useragent check), route the request to googlebot and googlebot grab the actual page from real app server. Not sure if that's supported : )

Comment: it would be but it wouldn't been harder to implement, is a different approach that some people suggest, but since I don't have any of the templates or I don't do any of those processes in the server it was easier to render with phantom. Any case is different tho.

Answer (score 0):

We are in the same situation. The simple solution is to use Open Graph meta tags in the pages your server will serve to Facebook scrapers.
Basically you need to do server-side what your web app is doing client-side. Amount of work  highly depends on your hosting technology (MVC makes it super easy), your URI format and the APIs you use.

You will find some explanations here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Open graph introduction:
http://ogp.me/